# Unable to open project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to open a project for an Android Studio tutorial book in Android Studio and running into a lot of problems. The latest problem is when trying to build the project, getting an error:

> 10:11 PM  Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method:
> SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
> The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
> To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
> Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 538 ms)

Any ideas what is going on here? Using Android Studio 4.1